# C++ Return reference to vector of non-copy objects

Tags: c++, reference, return, move

I have class `A` with disabled copy semantics and class `B` which contains vector of `A`'s. How can I write a member function of B that returns reference to the vector of `A`'s?.

For those knowing Rust here is what I am trying to do (expressed in the Rust language):

```rust
struct A {/* ... */}

struct B {
    data: Vec<A>,
}

impl B {
    pub fn data(&self) -> &Vec<A> {
        &self.data
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on "this doesn’t work"? It compiles fine here: https://godbolt.org/z/aMKz6636K

Comment: It the receiver also a reference or is it an object?

Comment: @op414 if you try (for eg. in main()) call data on object of type B compilation fails with error: [https://godbolt.org/z/6WrWhr68b](https://godbolt.org/z/6WrWhr68b)

Comment: Compilation fails because you're trying to copy the vector, which you have prohibited. Try `auto& data = b.data();` (And please: [mcve].)

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you, that worked! I thought auto will choose proper reference type. What's wrong with my example? I Abstracted away everything non relevant from my code and included only needed parts.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze `auto` is never a reference type.

Comment: you shouldnt fix the code in your question and not answer the question in the question. You can write an answer below, but questions are for the question and for the non-working code.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Is that ok?

Comment: the question would be better with the broken c++ code included. The answer starts with "...my error was ..." but in the quesiton there is no error. Its not clear what error or code the answer refers to.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number but it turned out there was no error. Or rather there was but not in the place I was expecting it. Now my questions precisely states, well my question, and answer answers it.

Comment: you had broken C++ code in the question before and the answer refers to that. Question and answer are phrased in a way that only you (and others that know the edit-history) can understand. Why not re-add the code that did not work as expected to the question? Just saying, once the question is fixed there are most likely duplicates anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @molbdnilo stated my error was that I used `auto data = b.data();` instead of `auto& data = b.data();`. Therefore following example is working and shows how to do what I asked:

```cpp
#include<vector>
class A
{
public:
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = default;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(A&&) = default;
private:
    /* some data */
};

class B
{
public:
    B(): m_data {} {}
    const std::vector<A>& data() const {
        return this->m_data;
    }
private:
    std::vector<A> m_data;
};

int main()
{
    auto b = B();
    auto& data = b.data();
}
```

Comment: There's a trick you can do in case you don't want to worry about cv-qualifiers:
`decltype(auto) data = b.data();`
That should automatically pick the cv-qualifiers from the type on the rvalue (in this case it'll evaluate to `const&`). It's a bit clunky, but saves you from having to take a look at the return type and caring to specify explicitly. Not that readable, though.